# How to do a git post-push?

Tags: linux, git, devops, webhooks, githooks

I have a git server where many of my repositories are being handled. I have a Raspberry Pi (which is globally accessible) setup in testing department. What I want to do is, I want to push the code from my PC to git server and that Raspberry Pi would automatically detect the push and do a subsequent git pull to update its repository.

I have used GitHub and it is VERY easy to do that in Github as it has a builtin Webhook page where I added a link of one of the php files in my Pi. That php file contains nothing but `git pull` so whenever I push something from my PC to GitHub, it executes that php file in Pi and it does a git pull and updates itself automatically.

I have also used a githook post-receive but it needs to setup on server and client both and it was a lot of work but I finally did it. still the repo was not being updated as I pushed the code.

I want to do the same exact thing which Github is doing but with Git. I am using Gitolite for managing Git on my server

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/metajack/notify-webhook

Comment: As a sidenote: Github provides a superset of features. Just because it's easy to do something on github does not mean the feature by itself is easy. (That's why you can pay for github. It's there business model.) When you are using gitolite you either have to live with its constraints or you do the hard work by solving that problem and make it easy yourself. It's a tradeoff: Either pay for an existing solution, or invest time and resources in a custom solution that is either opensource or selfowned.

Comment: @k0pernikus I did this method too. It did not work. I know it is going to be hard but if someone could guide me the way it would be nice.